# Getting an error on a Postgres table "ERROR: column does not exist" that doesn't make sense to me

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

In pgAdmin if I do a simple select:
`"select * from NFT where item_id = 1271"` I get what I would expect:
[image]

However, when I try to query on this other column: `"select * from NFT where tokenID = 40"` I get an error: "ERROR:  column "tokenid" does not exist

I'm new to Postgres in the last year, have used it quite a bit but this one has me stuck on how to proceed. It's just a normal column.

any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an English keyboard? Could you try the query like ```select * from NFT where tokenid = 40``` where 'I' is lower case.

Comment: i've tried it on standard xps 15 9570 US Dell laptop and with keyboard connected to laptop.  same result. I tried and it still didn't work. also tried nft.tokenid and nft.tokenID.. very strange.  it is of type bigint.   this only does not work in pgadmin.  when i use eloquent to do the query via php it works fine so it's not that big of a deal for me... but i'd still like to understand why this happens.